# Basis and dimension with finite vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve the following problems:

Considering the linear independet vectors $\vec T_1, ..., \vec T_s \in \mathbb{R}^s$ and the numbers $n_1, ... n_s \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$,

- How can I check the vectors

  $n_s \vec T_s, n_s \vec T_s + n_{s-1} \vec T_{s-1}, ...,  n_s \vec
     T_s + n_{s-1} \vec T_{s-1} + ... + n_1 \vec T_1$

  compose a $\mathbb{R}^s$ basis?
- Considering $1 \le p \le s$ and the subspace

  $\begin{equation} W = \langle n_s    \vec T_s, n_s \vec T_s + n_{s-1}
     \vec T_{s-1}, ...,  n_s \vec       T_s + n_{s-1} \vec T_{s-1}    +
     ... +    n_p \vec T_p \rangle    \end{equation}$,

  how can I calculate $W$ dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ be a basis of the vector space $V$.

**First fact.** The set
$$
\{v_1,v_1+v_2,\dots,v_1+\dots+v_{n-1},v_1+\dots+v_n\}
$$
is a basis of $V$.

*Proof.* Setting $w_k=v_1+\dots+v_k$, we have
$$
v_1=w_1,\quad v_2=w_2-w_1,\quad v_3=w_3-w_2,\quad \dots,\quad v_n=w_n-w_{n-1}
$$
Hence the set $\{w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n\}$ spans $V$. QED

**Second fact.** If $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n$ are nonzero scalars, the set
$$
\{c_1v_1,c_2v_2,\dots,c_nv_n\}
$$
is a basis of $V$.

*Proof.* We have $v_k=c_k^{-1}(c_kv_k)$, so the set spans $V$. QED

**Third fact.** For $1\le k\le n$, the set $\{v_1,v_1+v_2,\dots,v_1+\dots+v_k\}$ is linearly independent.

*Proof.* It is a subset of a basis. QED

Now translate this in your notation and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is easy. Just check
$$a_sn_s \vec T_s+a_{s-1}( n_s \vec T_s + n_{s-1} \vec T_{s-1})+ ...+ a_1(  n_s \vec
   T_s + n_{s-1} \vec T_{s-1} + ... + n_1 \vec T_1)=0$$
Rearrange it and obtain
$$(a_s+a_{s-1}+\cdots+a_1)n_s\vec T_s+\cdots+(a_2+a_1)n_2\vec T_2+a_1n_1\vec T_1=0$$
Since $(\vec T_s, \cdots, \vec T_1)$ is linearly independent, $(a_s+a_{s-1}+\cdots+a_1)n_s=0, \cdots, (a_2+a_1)n_2=0$, and $a_1n_1=0$. Now since $n_i\ne 0$, all $a_i=0$. Hence, $(n_s \vec T_s, n_s \vec T_s + n_{s-1} \vec T_{s-1}, ...,  n_s \vec
   T_s + n_{s-1} \vec T_{s-1} + ... + n_1 \vec T_1)$ is linearly independent. Since the length of the list is $s$, it is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^s$.

I am learning LA right now. Haven't got that far. Don't know the meaning of the second part.